# Sumifs to Pivot Tables (Excel 2016)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2016

My current role maintains and updates reports created in Excel. I'm on the process of cleaning the source sheets for the dashboard.

I want to create a pivot table based on the table below:

```
Record (A) | Created_Month (B) | Report_Month (C)
Entry 1    | Feb-17            | May-17
Entry 2    | Mar-17            | May-17
Entry 3    | Apr-17            | May-17
Entry 4    | May-17            | May-17
Entry 5    | May-17            | May-17
Entry 6    | May-17            | Jun-17
Entry 7    | Apr-17            | Jun-17
Entry 8    | Jan-17            | Jun-17
Entry 9    | Feb-17            | Jun-17
Entry 10   | May-17            | Jun-17
Entry 11   | Jun-17            | Jun-17
Entry 12   | Jun-17            | Jun-17
```

So we receive an Excel file with data table similar above. I just need to report the number of entries created on the same month as the reporting month. So for example, for Jun-17, there are 2 entries created. Using COUNTIFS, this data could be extracted but I want to do it in Pivot tables with Reporting_Month as the column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For robustness, turn your original data into an Excel Table object with Insert > Table or Ctrl-T. Then, with any table cell selected, click Insert > PivotTable. Drag the Report Month field into the Rows area and drag the Record field into the values, where, since it is text, it will default to Count.

[image]

Edit after comment: add a column to your data source with a formula that checks if the two months are the same and return the correct value. Then use that column as a filter in the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I'm quite new here (used to be viewer only) and I'm still learning how to do things around here. Anyway, I tried your suggestion. But what I really want to do is to have the pivot get the sum of entries with Created_Month=Report_Month. There should only 2 entries each for May and June. Filters won't do since it would only mean to filter the sum for all report month. I tried calculated field/item but I'm quite confused on how to use them yet. Hoping for your inputs. thanks you!

Comment: For that you need to add a column to your data source with a formula that checks if the two months are the same and return the correct value. Then use that column as a filter in the pivot table.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck with the idea of using only the data i have. :)

Comment: Great. I added this to the answer. Please mark the post as the answer as described in the [Tour]. That is how you can say thanks around here.